# are deleted entries counted in the load factor of a hash table using open addressing

Tags: hashtable, hash, load-factor

When calculating the load factor of a hashtable with an open-addressing  array implementation I am using:

```
numberOfKeysInArray/sizeOfArray
```

however it occurred to me that since deleted entries must be marked as such (to distinguish them from empty spaces), it might make sense to include these in the number of keys.

My thinking is that as far as estimating the average number of probes to find an entry, deleted entries should count towards the load factor, but as far as inserting a new key they should not.

Which is the proper calculation: including deleted keys or not?

Comment: P.S. could we have an open-addressing tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, by definition, load factor is the ratio of number of elements to bucket array size.  See e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_factor_%28computer_science%29#Load_factor) or [this lecture](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs312/2008sp/lectures/lec20.html).

There would also be a practical problem with counting delted entries in the load factor.  Most implementations have a maximum load factor.  If actual surpasses the maximum allowed, backing array size is increased.  If deleted entries counted towards higher load factor, this could cause unnecessary array size increase for an almost empty but high on debris contents table.

Comment: If each item keeps a flag or counter that says whether it's needed as a "stepping stone" for something else, and deleted items disappear entirely when they're not needed, having a large number of "stepping stones" could be a sign that a table should be expanded and rehashed.  If a table is properly sized, I wouldn't think there should need to be very many "deleted item" stepping stones within it even if many items are added and removed.